# need this to return what is entered

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Bigger{

public static void main(String [] args)
{
// declare variables
Scanner keyboardIn = new Scanner(System.in);
String userName = new String();
String fName = new String();
int numberLetters = 0;
int bigLetters=0;
char firstLetter;

// get user name from the user
System.out.print("Please enter your user name: ");
userName = keyboardIn.nextLine();

 // get second name from the user
System.out.print("Please enter your second name: ");

 fName = keyboardIn.nextLine();

 // use an appropriate method to find the number of letters
 numberLetters = userName.length();
 bigLetters = fName.length();

if(numberLetters > bigLetters)
{
    System.out.print("String 1 Is the longest string ");
}
else
{
    System.out.print("String 2 Is the longest string "); 
 }
 }
 }
```

I need this to print out the actual string with the actual letters so if Denmark is the bigger string i need it to print this out to the user. How do i do this?

Regards,

Mark

Comment: Start by telling us what problem you're experiencing.

Comment: This is not the place for code review. If you have a specific question about code then you need to explicitly ask it. Otherwise people are unlikely to debug your code for you.

Comment: So... `System.out.print(userName + " Is the longest string ");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should actually also check to see if the entered strings are equal in length (The following can be shortened to check greater than or equal to using using `>=` or less than or equal to `<=` if required):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Bigger {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // get user name from the user
    System.out.print("Please enter your user name: ");
    String userName = input.nextLine();
    // get second name from the user
    System.out.print("Please enter your second name: ");
    String secondName = input.nextLine();

    // use an appropriate method to find the number of letters and prompt user
    if(userName.length() == secondName.length()) {
      System.out.println(userName + " is equal in length than " + secondName);
    } else if(userName.length() > secondName.length()) {
      System.out.println(userName + " is longer in length than " + secondName);
    } else {
      System.out.println(userName + " is shorter in length than " + secondName);
    }
  }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Please enter your user name:  MarkDoherty
Please enter your second name:  Denmark
MarkDoherty is longer in length than Denmark
```

Alternatively you could use string formatting like so:

```
// use an appropriate method to find the number of letters
if(userName.length() == secondName.length()) {
  System.out.printf("%s (%d characters long) is equal in length than %s (%d characters long)\n", userName, userName.length(), secondName, secondName.length());
} else if(userName.length() > secondName.length()) {
  System.out.printf("%s (%d characters long) is longer in length than %s (%d characters long)\n", userName, userName.length(), secondName, secondName.length());
} else {
  System.out.printf("%s (%d characters long) is shorter in length than %s (%d characters long)\n", userName, userName.length(), secondName, secondName.length());
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Please enter your user name:  MarkDoherty
Please enter your second name:  Denmark
MarkDoherty (11 characters long) is longer in length than Denmark (7 characters long)
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FuUP/1)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, the easiest way would be to just concatenate whatever string you need to print out with the variable inside of the `System.out.print()`. For example, if I have a variable of type `String` called `myString` I would use the line of code:

```
System.out.print("This is my string variable" + myString);
```

Also, unless you want everything on one line be sure you are appending newlines to the end of your string or use `System.out.println()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You all were extremely helpful.

Comment: my question was answered. I just needed the program to accept two names from the user and then print out the name that was the longest. I could only get it to display which of variables had the longest name so it was only saying variable 1 is bigger or variable 2 is bigger. I wanted it so that it would return the biggest variable and the contents of that variable. I'll take more care in asking a question next time now that i know you all are very sensititve.